# Reduce compilation times and dependencies using friend class

Tags: c++, templates, friend, friend-function

In one of my projects I have a tree data structure, that might contain values of a generic type `T`.

In order to reduce compilation times and dependencies I tried to move implementation details from the tree node class `Node` to class `NodeImpl`. The internals of `Node` are private and should be only accessed at defined entry points, for example by the `getName` function.

Only people that are interested in using `getName` should include `NodeImpl` in their source files. This is how I think to reduce my compilation times and dependencies.

But for some reason the following three toys classes will not compile. It says no access to private members. What I'm doing wrong?

File `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Node.h"
#include "NodeImpl.h"

int main(int argc, char** args) {
    Node<int> n("Test", 2);
    std::cout << getName(n) << std::endl;
}
```

File `Node.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

template<typename T>
class NodeImpl;

template<typename T>
class Node {
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    Node(const std::string& name, const T& value) : name(name), value(value) {}

private:
    std::string name;
    T value;
    friend class NodeImpl<T>;
};
```

File `NodeImpl.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include "Node.h"

template<typename T>
std::string getName(Node<T>& n);

template<typename T>
class NodeImpl {
    NodeImpl(Node<T>& node) : mNode(node) {
    }
    Node<T>& mNode;

    std::string name() {
        return mNode.name;
    }

    friend std::string getName(Node<T>& n);
};

template<typename T>
std::string getName(Node<T>& n) {
    auto x = NodeImpl<T>(n);
    return x.name();
}
```

Comment: Friends of your friends aren't your friends

Comment: Thanks for the help. Of course friend declaration is not transitive. I changed `NodeImpl.h`. Thought this was the solution. But still it is not compiling. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [warning produced by GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eed1c3be25100117) gives insight:

```
warning: friend declaration 'std::__cxx11::string getName(Node<T>&)' declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]
 friend std::string getName(Node<T>& n);
                                      ^
note: (if this is not what you intended, make sure the function template has already been declared and add <> after the function name here)
```

In other words, your class `NodeImpl<int>` was befriending a global function `std::string getName(Node<int> &)`, which is unrelated to the function `std::string getName<int>(Node<int> &)` instantiated from the function template `template <class T> std::string getName(Node<T> &)` for `T = int`.

So the correct solution is this:

```
template<typename T>
class NodeImpl {
    // ... as before ...

    friend std::string getName<T>(Node<T>& n);
};
```

This [[live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e08c103a561c85c5) shows that this solution indeed works.

Comment: That is so amazing. I'm using Visual Studio. Many thanks. :-)